# Change Flask-Microblog navbar background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been working through a few Flask tutorials and I've been using Corey's Flask app as an example to work from.

https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/02-Templates

I'd like to change the navbar background and I've been trying to get my head around his use of static/main.css

In templates/layout.html there is the following tag for the navbar;

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">`

This seems to correspond to .bg-steel in main.css but I tried changing the color but this didn't seem to work.

```
.bg-steel {
  background-color: #c42d3a;
}
```

I finally managed to override with the following but I wonder if there's a cleaner way to integrate with this main.css as it seems like an efficient approach if I can get my head around it..

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: #16239e;">`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Corey Schafer's Flask tutorial - changing background colour in *main.css* didn't seem to have any effect.

This is because CSS doesn't automatically update when you make code changes.

When running your app locally, you need to clear your browser cache to view the new CSS. You can do this in Safari via the Develop menu in the toolbar, then select "Empty caches".

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the css override to work either, and used your suggested "workaround".   I subsequently found that Bootstrap's official documentation suggests the same thing:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes

Provided your navbar is imported into a base template, (meaning you only have one navbar.html in the app, which you import into base.html with  {% include 'navbar.html' %}) it seems efficient enough.

Note that if you have something like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="background-color: #8cd98c;">
```

you won't see the change because `bg-dark` will take precedence.   Needs to be

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #8cd98c;">
```

Also note that by over-riding the background colour, you have to take care of choosing the correct `navbar-dark`/`navbar-light` value in order for your navbar text to be sufficiently light or dark to be readable with your new background colour.